# Move data from field to field in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

In MS Access I have a table like this:

```
TABLE USER
Id (int)
Status (text)
OldStatus (text)
```

I would like to create a MS Access Query which, when executed, moves the content of Status field to the top of OldStatus, and adds the current year. For example:

**Before execution:**

```
ID    STATUS       OLDSTATUS
1     Very good    [2010] Excelent
                   [2009] Very bad

2     Excelent     [2010] Bad
                   [2009] Good
```

**After execution:**

```
ID    STATUS       OLDSTATUS
1                  [2011] Very good
                   [2010] Excelent
                   [2009] Very bad

2                  [2011] Excelent
                   [2010] Bad
                   [2009] Good
```

How can I do that? THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't know the name of your table, so you'll have to substitute. The goal here is to maintain the old status while concatenating the current status.  I used a space (" ") to put between, but you can use any character you want.

```
Update Status_Table
Set OLDSTATUS = OLDSTATUS & " " & STATUS
```

For what it is worth, there is a better way.  Create a StatusHistory table:

```
StatusHistoryID
, StatusID
, Status
, Status_Date
```

You would have more flexibility here. Reports could be set for a date range or a particular year. You're table would be very hard to run a report on the status for 2010.

Comment: Agreed, much better to create a history table. user411103's table organisation isn't even 1NF (1st normal form), and they or their successor are in form much pain and tears later on if they ever have to work with the OLDSTATUS column.